# Use menu in panels

Tags: routes, panels

I have problem. I have panel page with 2 columns. On the left I have menu, and on the right I want to have a content from this menu, how can I have static menu on the left, and only change the content on right? Do you have any proposition or suggestions?

Comment: on the quick you'll maybe find something here http://drupal.org/node/443208

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[block menu](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block)** model this give you a dynamic menu but if you want a static menu you have to add a menu from(admin/structure/menu) after create the menu it will show on blocks(admin/structure/block) and put it on the specific region and you have  a region called content this is by default show the content on it 
see that http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTZT_ucpYMQ

Answer (score 0):

In general you can create a menu that calls a URL to a view and then use the View to provide the desired content.  You will find more on how to use Panels [here](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager) and views [here](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone)

Answer (score 0):

Ashlar's answer is correct, but I would like to add some more background info.

Any menu item is linked to a specific callback in Drupal. A callback may or may not be handled by the Page manager and rendered through Panels. A callback rendered with Panels may or may not have your specific two column layout. There is no way to use Panels to "force" any specific piece of content to render in a specific Panel region, that's just not how it works.

You are responsible for ensuring that each link in the menu points to a page that is rendered with the two column layout. One common, and good, way of doing that is what Ashlar suggests. However, this will not necessarily work for all types of content.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using different module to perform the desired functionality you could simply make node template pages so that the menu remains the same and there is only a change in the content.

To Add node template pages you

1. Go to structure -> Pages -> Node template -> Enable and Edit
2. Add Variant on the top. Add as many variants that you need to add.
   In the Selection rule select add the **Node Bundle** and select the Content type that that you want to display.
3. Select the type of layout from the **Layout** option.
4. In the content part click on Add Content and select what do you want to put there in the display.